# setTimeout sequence is bypassing a previous setInterval basically nullifying the setInterval event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a slot machine which has a re-spin feature (which is identified as stampede in the code) on random wins like the machine Haywire in the casinos.

The initial spin/win works fine... after a random re-spin(s) is generated script then randomly selects the number of re-spins awarded and calls `stampede()` which loops through the number of spins awarded.

`stampede()` itself is in a 'setTimeout()' which will delay its start if a big win is hit on the initial win for a congrats screen to run... this works fine.

The reel annimation on the spin is handled by `setInterval()` for each reel. The problem is that this code is being bypassed by the stop reel code which is in a set of `setTimeOut()`functions used to stop the reels. It goes directly to the stop reel.

The loop itself works fine in regards to sliding the stampede announcement screen in and out and adjusting the "show win and bank add on screen" with the exception of the `.animateNumber()` not working inside of the `stampede()`.

Both the code to animate the reels and stop them work fine outside of the `stampede()` but as stated the reel animation does not work in `stampede()`...

Here is my Code:

```
// check for respin
        var respinCount = 0;
        var respinCheck = randItem(1, 1000);        
        if((+respinCheck) <= 899){respinCount = 0}
        else if((+respinCheck) >= 900 && (+respinCheck) <= 950){respinCount = 1;}
        else if((+respinCheck) >= 951 && (+respinCheck) <= 970){respinCount = 2;}
        else if((+respinCheck) >= 971 && (+respinCheck) <= 980){respinCount = 3;}
        else if((+respinCheck) >= 981 && (+respinCheck) <= 990){respinCount = 4;}
        else if((+respinCheck) >= 991 && (+respinCheck) <= 999){respinCount = 5;}
        else if((+respinCheck) == 1000){respinCount = 10;}

        // adjust stampede delay if win is >= 100
        if(win >= 100){var stampede_delay = 7000;}else if (win <= 99){var stampede_delay = 10;}

        setTimeout(function() {// stampede delay

            if(respinCount == 0){respinCount = 3;} // for testing stampede

            if(respinCount >= 1){
                // turn off auto spin if active
                if(auto_set == 1){ auto_set = 0; $("#autoData").val(auto_set);
                if($("#auto_spin").hasClass("active")){$("#auto_spin").removeClass("active");}}                 

                // stampede()
                (function stampede(i) {          
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        // announce stampede
                        $("#stampede_wrap").slideDown().delay(700).slideUp();                           

                        // make reel stop transparent
                        $("#reel_1").html('<img src="images/stop-images/transparent.png">');
                        $("#reel_2").html('<img src="images/stop-images/transparent.png">');
                        $("#reel_3").html('<img src="images/stop-images/transparent.png">');

                        // add reel sprite class to reels
                        if (!$('#reel_1').hasClass("reel-1-sprite")){$('#reel_1').addClass('reel-1-sprite')};
                        if (!$('#reel_2').hasClass("reel-2-sprite")){$('#reel_2').addClass('reel-2-sprite')};
                        if (!$('#reel_3').hasClass("reel-3-sprite")){$('#reel_3').addClass('reel-3-sprite')};

                        // annimate reels
                        var x = 0; var xx = 0; var xxx = 0; // reel increment variables 
                        var r1a = setInterval(function(){   // annimate/stop reel_1
                            if(ar.length == x){x = 0;}
                            else {$('.reel-1-sprite').css("background-position", aru[x]); x++;}
                        },0);
                        var r2a = setInterval(function(){   // annimate/stop reel_2
                            if(ar.length == xx){xx = 0;}
                            else {$('.reel-2-sprite').css("background-position", ar[xx]); xx++;}
                        },0);
                        var r3a = setInterval(function(){   // annimate/stop reel_3
                            if(ar.length == xxx){xxx = 0;}
                            else {$('.reel-3-sprite').css("background-position", aru[xxx]); xxx++;}
                        },0);


                        // stop reels
                        setTimeout(function() {             // stop reel_1          
                        $("#reel_1").removeClass("reel-1-sprite"); 
                        $("#reel_1").html('<img src="images/stop-images/'+rn1sc+'.png">');      
                        }, 800);
                        setTimeout(function() {             // stop reel_2      
                        $("#reel_2").removeClass("reel-2-sprite"); 
                        $("#reel_2").html('<img src="images/stop-images/'+rn2sc+'.png">');      
                        }, 1000);
                        setTimeout(function() {             // stop reel_3      
                        $("#reel_3").removeClass("reel-3-sprite"); 
                        $("#reel_3").html('<img src="images/stop-images/'+rn3sc+'.png">');
                        }, 1200);

                        // adjust bank for this stampede spin
                        pBank = ((+bank) + (+win_value)); updateBank(uid,pBank); bank = (+pBank);
                        $("#creditData,#bankData").val((+bank)); $("#winData").val((+win_value)); 

                        // show win and bank add on screen
                        var comma_separator = $.animateNumber.numberStepFactories.separator(',');
                        $('#thisWin').animateNumber({ number: win_value, numberStep: comma_separator },500);
                        $('#credit_count_text').prop('number', (+now)).animateNumber({ number:(+bank), numberStep:comma_separator},500);
                        $("#creditData").val((+bank));

                        if (--i) stampede(i);
                   }, 2000)
                })(respinCount); // end stampede
            }; // end if(respinCount >= 1)

        }, stampede_delay); // end stampede delay
```

I am at a loss... any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance Pete

Comment: Make the portion that stops the reels a named function like `stopReels()` then you can call on `stampede()` and `stopReels()` separately. And also a named function for animate reels, like `spinReels()`

Comment: Thanks for the feed back @zer00ne... I place the stop code itself inside of a setTimeOut() and it worked... however, I did go ahead and place both the animate and stop code in functions... it seems to be working fine now. thanks

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. When you declare a function, you call it whenever needed because it's hoisted and available instantly. With an anonymous function and the referenced functions you have, they can't be used until your'e at that point of the code. That makes things overtly complicated, especially if you use `setTimeout`